# Detect if T is a reference member at compile time

Tags: c++, constexpr, compile-time-type-checking

I'm trying to detect if an argument is a reference member, at compile time. It does not catch it and I can't figure it why.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct a {
 a(): i1(42), i2(i1){}
 int  i1;
 int& i2;
};

template <typename T>
void Field(T &field) {

    if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>) {
        //handle pointer
    } else if constexpr (std::is_reference_v<T>) {
        static_assert(!std::is_reference_v<T>, "Reference not supported");
    } else {
        //handle value
    }
}


int main()
{
    a a_;

    Field(a_.i2); // I want this to fail at compile time, but it's not
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This isn't possible without macros. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: @JeJo that expression is always `true`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm writing serialization library and want to disable raw pointer and references.

Comment: Presumably you only want to disable references as class members? Because doing something like `void foo(T &x) {deserialize(x);}` looks fine to me. You're going to have some mechanism of listing class members, and your [de]serialization functions will loop over such member lists, that's where you should check for references.

Comment: Changing signature to `template <typename C, typename T> void Field(C& c, T C::*field)`? Then you can check type/properties of `T`. Call would be then `Field(a_, &a::i2);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 The problem with that approach is you can't take a pointer-to-data-member for a reference data member. https://godbolt.org/z/8sxhhPoj9

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: As OP wants to forbid that, it is fine ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::is_reference_v` works in principle, but not the way you're using it. You have a function template `Field(T &field)`, where the template type parameter `T` is not going to be deduced to a reference.

```cpp
a a_;
Field(a_.i2); // calls Field<T>(T&) with [T = int]
              // std::is_reference_v<int> is false
```

Whatever, you're trying to do here, you could:

- not work with references directly, but use `std::reference_wrapper` and always accept a value parameter `T field`
- disable deduction by having a `std::type_identity_t<T> field` parameter, which forces the user to call `Field<int&>(a_.i2)` manually

  - this could possibly happen through a macro which expands to `Field<decltype(a_.i2)>(a_.i2)`

Comment: Thanks everyone. I wanted to have straight forward way of doing this. It's seems it's not so easy, so I'm just gonna "remember" not to try and serialize reference :) This is my personal project. I happy with Jan explanation. Now it make sens. Again thank you all.

Comment: @MariuszWitoldWisniewski I'm glad that this was helpful to you. By the way, if you consider this to solve the question, it would be great if you marked the answer as approved :)

Answer (score 0):

This is closest I can get to what I think you need.
I usually don't like to use macros but in this case it could paint me out of a corner. The idea is to use `decltype(field)` to select the correct template overload explicitly. And to use SFINAE to rule out reference and pointer types.
So instead of `if constexpr` with a `static_assert` the function will only compile for non-reference and non-pointer types.

Online demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/nkq6bdYD7

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    A() : i1(42), i2(i1) {}
    int  i1;
    int& i2;
    int* i3;
};

template<typename T>
static constexpr bool is_value()
{
     return !std::is_reference_v<T> && !std::is_pointer_v<T>;
}

template<typename T>
auto Field(const T& value) -> std::enable_if_t<is_value<T>(),void>
{
    std::cout << "Handling field : " << value;
}

#define FIELD(x) Field<decltype(x)>(x);

int main()
{
    A a;

    FIELD(a.i1);
    FIELD(a.i2); // <== will not compile
    FIELD(a.i3); // <== will not compile
    
    return 0;
}
```